# Design of DC-DC Converters

Tags: voltage, current, dc-dc-converter, buck, boost

While designing buck converters (or boost converters), why do we usually fix some percentage of the Ripple current (or ripple voltage) and from this percentage, we arrive at the value of inductor and other passive discrete components?

Why is the ripple current (or ripple voltage) central to the calculation of the other passive discrete components associated with the buck converter?

Comment: I'm not sure what this means: *why do we usually fix some percentage of the Ripple current (or ripple voltage)*

Comment: You can design to meet almost any specification; but you need that specification in the first place (so you know, when design meets spec, that you are done). That ripple is part of the specification.

Answer (score 0):

Ripple factor is just another way to express the amplitude of voltage ripple (in terms of the RMS peak-to-peak ripple vs. the absolute value of the DC voltage). High voltage ripple can cause jamming in radio circuitry, data corruption in digital circuitry, and tolerance violations in power circuitry. To put things simply, high ripple is not good, but typically it is a result of high-efficiency power supplies, which yields improved battery life and power consumption. So it presents a trade-off in electronics design.

In capacitors, power loss and internal heating are dependent on ripple current. The ripple current capability is one of the key parameters to consider when selecting a capacitor for a specific application. Therefore it serves as a central to the calculation of the other passive discrete components associated with the buck converter